# How to add custom elements to Wsse Security / Username Token in Suds

Tags: soap, suds, wsse, usernametoken

Default SOAP Username Token has the following elements:

```
 <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
 </wsse:UsernameToken>
```

For the same I would to like an additional tokens say Domain & Organization, the schema should look like this,

```
 <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
        <Organization>ORGANIZATION</Organization>
        <Domain>DOMAIN</Domain>
 </wsse:UsernameToken>
```

So using Element tag, I appended the elements, here it goes.

```
wsse = ('wsse', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext')
security = Element('Security', ns=wsse)

usernametoken = Element('UsernameToken', ns=wsse)

usernametoken.insert(Element('Username', ns=wsse).setText('USERNAME'))
usernametoken.insert(Element('Password', ns=wsse).setText('PASSWORD'))
usernametoken.insert(Element('Organization').setText('ORGANIZATION'))
usernametoken.insert(Element('Domain').setText('DEFAULT'))

security.insert(usernametoken)
```

Now when I try to set options for the same:

```
client.set_options(wsse=security)
```

Am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: "wsse" must be: (<class suds.wsse.Security at 0xf552c0>,)
```

Looks like the type of token class is being changed... Am I missing something

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

client setting options should be soapheader instead of wsse, here the code goes

```
client.set_options(soapheaders=security)
```